# Arrange dataframe inside a for loop in R

Tags: r, dplyr

In the code below I want to create subsets of df by column and afterwards sorting it by the specific rank variable. The code does not return any errors, but does not work after all.

```
df <- data <- data.frame(
      id=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),
      rank1=c(1,3,2,1,5,7),
      rank2=c(4,6,2,1,4,2),
      rank3=c(4,6,2,1,4,2))
    
    for (i in colnames("df")){
      assign(as.name(i), data.frame(df) %>%
               select(id, as.name(i))) %>%
              arrange(as.name(i))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object to be `assign` should be string and `i` is a string if we use `colnames(df)` without quoting the `"df"`

```
for(i in colnames(df)[-1]) {
     assign(i, df %>% 
                select(id, all_of(i)) %>% 
                arrange(across(all_of(i))))
  }
```

This will create objects 'rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3' in the global environmewnt with columns 'id' and the rank column in each of those

-output

```
> rank1
  id rank1
1  a     1
2  d     1
3  c     2
4  b     3
5  e     5
6  f     7
> rank2
  id rank2
1  d     1
2  c     2
3  f     2
4  a     4
5  e     4
6  b     6
> rank3
  id rank3
1  d     1
2  c     2
3  f     2
4  a     4
5  e     4
6  b     6
```

---

The OP's code block was not executing as the `colnames("df")` returns `NULL` and the iteration on `NULL` returns nothing

```
for(i in NULL) print(i)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Any idea why I was not getting an error on my (now) obviously wrong code?

Comment: @fahans your code was not executing as `colnames("df")` returns NULL

Comment: I just accepted it, wait time was still in place when I commented.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on why it was not executing!

Comment: @fahans You can check that with print i.e. `for(i in NULL) print(i)`

Comment: Follow up on the opening question. I decided, that I want to reduce the subset dataframes to the newly ordered id column and combine all of those to a new dataframe, which only contains the different ranked IDs.

This is the code: 


`rankings <- data.frame(`
            rank=1:55
)

for(i in colnames(df)[-1]) {
  assign(i, df %>% 
           arrange(desc(across(all_of(i)))) %>%
           select(id) )#%>%
           #rename(all_of(i) = id))
  
  rankings <- rankings %>%
    cbind(i)
  
}

`

Neither the rename, nor the cbind work though.

Comment: @fahans If you are using the same approach, then get those data as `mget(ls(pattern = '^rank\\d+$')) %>% bind_cols`

Comment: I'm sorry for the weird formation in my comment. I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: I read your comment as the combine the rank datasets to a single data.  So, mget returns the object values in a list and then do bind_cols to bind the columns of the list of dataset to a single one

Comment: @fahans can you post as a new question as from the comments it is not clear to me

Comment: @fahans that code is a separate piece of code outside the `for` loop

Comment: I created a new question for clarification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377236/construct-new-ranked-columns-out-of-rank-columns-in-r)