# Construct new ranked columns out of rank columns in R

Tags: r

In the code below I create subsets of df by column and afterwards sorting it by the specific rank variable.

```
    df <- data.frame(
          id=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),
          rank1=c(1,3,2,1,5,7),
          rank2=c(4,6,2,1,4,2),
          rank3=c(4,6,2,1,4,2))
        
        for(i in colnames(df)[-1]) {
  assign(i, df %>% 
           arrange(desc(across(all_of(i)))) %>%
           select(id))
}
```

Now I want to combine these ranked subsets into a new dataframe with one rank variable. This creates the new dataframe:

```
rankings <- data.frame(
            rank=1:6
)
```

How do I merge the new dataframe with the ranked subsets of my original dataframe? Preferably the columns should have the name of their ranking (rank1, rank2, rank3), so a rename is probably needed in the loop as well, which I can't get to work, too.

Comment: What is `aggregated`

Comment: Remnant from my actual code - I corrected it. Sorry!

Comment: In the code, you are `select`ing id instead of the column for rank i.e. should that be `select(all_of(i))`

Comment: Which is what I want to do. In the final dataframe I want to slice the first 15 rows and then compare the overlap between the top15 in the different ranking systems.

Comment: It is not clear how you got `1:55` as expected when you are selecting id

Comment: the column containing 1:55 is a unique rank identifier in the new dataframe. just something to order by.

EDIT: My bad! 55 is the length of the columns in my actual data frame

Comment: Example code should now be correct

Comment: Your `rank1$id#
[1] "f" "e" "b" "c" "a" "d"` the values in expected is 1:6.  How are tou getting those 1 to 6 from this id

Comment: 1 to 6 is the first column from my new data frame. I want to append `rank1$id`and so on to this dataframe.

Comment: Can you check the solution I posted.  I am not still not sure how your expected would look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current code of creating multiple objects in the env, get those objects into a `list` with `mget` by specifying the `pattern` argument of `ls` to match the object name substring, then loop over the `list` with `imap`, `rename` the 'id' column with name of the list element (`.y`), bind them to a single dataset column wise (`_dfc`), and then bind with the 'rankings' data as well

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mget(ls(pattern = '^rank\\d+$')) %>%
     imap_dfc(~ .x %>%
                  rename(!! .y := id)) %>%
     bind_cols(rankings, .)
```

-output

```
#   rank rank1 rank2 rank3
#1    1     f     b     b
#2    2     e     a     a
#3    3     b     e     e
#4    4     c     c     c
#5    5     a     f     f
#6    6     d     d     d
```

---

Also, instead of doing the `assign` to create multiple objects and then gathering those objects from the global env, this can be done in a more straightforward way by looping `across` the columns that have 'rank', return the 'id' column based on the `order` of those columns in descending and then create the `rank` column as sequence of rows (`row_number()`)

```
df %>% 
    transmute(across(contains('rank'), ~ id[order(-.)])) %>%
    mutate(rank = row_number(), .before = 1)
#  rank rank1 rank2 rank3
#1    1     f     b     b
#2    2     e     a     a
#3    3     b     e     e
#4    4     c     c     c
#5    5     a     f     f
#6    6     d     d     d
```

Comment: This works for my example code! My actual data set the rank column names differ though. As in "rank1", ranking_system", "another_ranking_system". I am sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: @fahans Then, you can change the `pattern = 'rank'` to match any rank object in the global env or use `pattern = 'rank\\d+$|ranking_system$'`

Comment: @fahans I updated with a more straightforward approach to tackle this